# Access most recent cmd command from Visual Basic

Tags: visual-studio, cmd

Is there any way to access the most recent cmd command that was run from Visual Basic?
I am trying to make a cmd command that resolves websites' IP Addresses and I'm trying to make it so you could type "resolve google.com", but for that to happen I need to access the command in order to know that google.com was the website that you are trying to resolve.

Any help?

Comment: So, in essence, you're trying to read command-line arguments?

Comment: Is this VBA, or is this some application you are writing with the use of Visual Studio as the IDE (e.g. VB.Net)?  Either way, the "visual-studio" tag is inappropriate - it should be used for problems with Visual Studio itself, not for problems with code being developed using Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

Sample from a quick VB.Net app in VS2015:

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()

        Dim arr() = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs

        For Each arg As String In arr
            Console.WriteLine(arg)
        Next

        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```

This reads the input arguments from commandline (separated by spaces) into an array, which you can peruse at your convenience.

The program waits for you to press enter before exiting, so you can see that it spits out the arguments you provided (if you should run the compiled .exe directly).